# UK national insurance increase impact on low and higher earners

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, national-insurance

National Insurance payments are increasing in the UK this April. I am seeing arguments against this that say the increase will have a higher impact on the lower paid.

[This BBC article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQGni.jpg) shows a new payment structure in an image (which I'm not allowed to embed in my post for some reason).

It than makes the following statement:

"There are concerns the increase will have a higher impact on the lower-paid.This is because workers pay 12% National Insurance on earnings between £9,564 (£9,880 from April) and £50,268. However, earnings above this amount attract a rate of just 2%.So, if your income rises above £50,000, National Insurance takes a smaller proportion of your wages."

But, I calculated the total new NI annual payment for both £20,000 income and £100,000 income - and my workings show that the NI payment makes up 6.7% of both wages.

1. Income: £20,000
   New April NI contribution: £1,340
   % of wage: 6.7%
2. Income: £100,000
   New April NI contribution: £6,967
   % of wage: £6.97%

Have I misunderstood the BBC comment about the way in which it will negatively impact people on lower incomes compared to those on higher incomes? Is the 12% Vs 2% rate only on a certain amount of their income, after a certain threshold, as opposed to the full income, in the way that I've worked out?

Comment: High earners pay the 12% rate on income up to £50,268 and then pay the lower 2% rate on income above that level.  As the high earner's income gets to be much larger than £50,268, the total payment approaches 2% of their income.  (e.g. try a salary of £1,000,000.)

Comment: Percentage of total income is much less important than that of truely disposable income. After tax, rent, fuel and food.

Comment: I think it's not the absolute %, but the % increase

Comment: Brian, of that £1,000,000 income, about £436,000 are income tax. That person pays 2.5% of their income, but over 4% of their taxed income.

Comment: PS. The BBCs chart is both useless and wrong. Having just four amounts make it impossible to understand the effect correctly. And they same to believe that NI contributions start at £12,570, they start at £9568. The extra payment at £20,000 is about £130, not £89.

Answer (score 1):

National Insurance is supposed to pay mostly for the NHS and your state pension, so it makes some sense that it gets reduced at some point, since neither your state pension nor your health cost will increase. And the reduction comes exactly at the point where your income tax jumps from 20% to 40%. (The effective income tax rate for income from £100,000 to £125,140 is 60%, and above £150,000 it is 45%).

If you calculate the change: Between £12,570 and £50,270, you pay 20% income tax plus 12% NI, leaving £68.00 out of every additional £100.00 income. This will go down to £66.75, or -1.84%. From £50,270 to £100,000, you currently pay 40% income tax and 2% NI, leaving £58.00 out of every £100.00 additional income, which will go down to £56.75, or -2.16%. So the percentage of your net income that is taken away for higher income is indeed slightly higher. And there is an anomaly for income from £100,000 to £125,140 where you lose £1.25 out of £38.00 for an additional £100.00 in income, which is a change of -3.29%.